# USB serial port

Tags: pi-4, serial

Trying to connect USB serial port device to raspberry Pi4.

But command below does not show any changes

```
ls -l /dev/tty*
```

I was expected to get new device that starts with `/dev/tty` . Correct me if I'm wrong.

How to solve missing com port problem?

UPD

This is CDC class device and serial device works fine on Windows.

I have tested by connecting device to Ubuntu and Pi4:

Ubuntu
`lsusb` brings additional line:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045b:5310 Hitachi, Ltd Crypto
```

`dmesg | grep tty` brings additional line:

```
cdc_acm 1-2.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

Pi4

`lsusb` brings additional line:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045b:5310 Hitachi, Ltd Crypto
```

`dmesg | grep tty` brings nothing

How to get serial device on Pi like it appears on Ubuntu onttyACM0 ?

Comment: start the Pi; plug in the device and check the log with `dmesg`

Comment: Are you sure the USB device is emulating a USB/CDC (Communications Device Class)? For instance, if it was emulating a USB/MSC (Mass Storage Class) then likely the built in LInux UDEV rules would create a /dev/sd* entry instead of a /dev/tty* entry.

Comment: Also, use the command "lsusb" before and after plugging in the USB device and let us know what changes.